# Enterprise app to private distribution in App Store

Tags: app-store-connect

we have developed an app and distributed it through our organization's internal portal using apple enterprise account. Now we want it to distribute it privately in the App store account. We have both AppStore and enterprise account of our organization. Do we need to change the bundle id of the app, if upload the same app for private distribution because it is registered with an enterprise account?

Comment: Perhaps a link to a tutorial/steps you used for publishing might help, otherwise it's just a waaay to generic to even guess properly even if somebody did a similar thing. Please provide some code or something more specific.

Comment: I recommend calling [Apple support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) and I think you will have the answer within a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

It always suggested to use unique Bundle ID for each app. Also consider using different bundle ID for the App which goes into Private Distribution.

Comment: No - this *is* an answer to the question - it's a self-contained answer that is attempting to provide a solution to the problem posed by the OP. If it's plausible that the OP accepts the answer, you shouldn't recommend deletion in the Low quality answers review queue - commend and/or downvote if you so wish.